# What is a simple version control solution for two team members that integrates with SSIS?

Tags: version-control, ssis

Team background: I work as part of a two man IT team, with our primary duty to perform ETL operations using SSIS. For the most part, our SSIS packages don't change, but over time, our algorithms for derived columns, etc do. We're looking for a simple version control solution to help manage these changes. Specifically, we'd like the ability to simply commit changes over time. If we decide that something isn't right, we want the ability to just go back to version 20 or w/e and make that our current primary version. We won't ever be working on one project at the same time and any other features are not really necessary.

Environment background: All of our ssis projects, along with their associated data, are currently stored on the R: drive, which is accessible as a local drive on both of our primary work machines. We make all changes and load all the data directly from that folder.

With this background, can anyone recommend a solution that meets this criteria?

I've done quite a bit of research so far and found most solutions to be total overkill for our scenario and probably not worth the effort in setup and maintenance. The software leading the way is VisualSVN + VisualSVN Server + TortoiseSVN, but I'm finding it difficult to use for our simple use case.

Are there any pieces of software that can perform the function I'm looking for? Any and all suggestions would be great. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you looking for a free or commercial product? Standalone or hosting version control?

Comment: We don't mind paying for a good commercial product that fits our needs. As far as hosting vs standalone, I'm not sure I understand what the difference is. If this helps, we would rather not have to move our main copies that we work from currently and would rather use our current hardware as we have plenty available. Thanks for the response

Comment: Standalone/hosting means whether to set up your own source control server. You may check out SourceAnywhere, which is a SQL Server based version control solution, and see if it fits your needs. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/version-control-source-control-sourceanywhere.aspx (Discaimer: I work for the company)